# Analytical solution for volume when a plane cuts a hemi-sphere

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

I need to find the analytical solution when the plane $ P: z = grad\cdot y + z_{cut} $ cuts the hemi-sphere $ S: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2;\:y \leq 0 $. I constructed two 3D images in MatLab of the problem statement:

[image: hemi-sphere sliced by a plane]
[image: volume to be determined]

The first image explicitly shows how the plane cuts the hemi-sphere, and the second image shows the volume that is desired to be known, i.e. the volume ($V$) included between the green shaded surfaces and the $XZ$-plane at $y = 0$.

For clarity, I will state the obvious: The plane may be thought of as a 2D line drawn on the $YZ$-axis and then symmetrically extruded in the $X$-direction. With this analogy, $z_{cut}$ is the $z$-coordinate where the plane cuts the $XZ$-plane at $y = 0$ and $grad$ is the gradient of the plane (with respect to the $YZ$-axis).

Now, $V$ can be divided into two smaller volumes:

1. The volume $V_{horis}$, obtained when the plane $z = z_{cut}$ cuts the hemi-sphere. This volume is easy to calculate, since it is the volume of a spherical cap at $h = z_{cut} + r$. The formula is $V_{horis} = \frac{1}{2}[\frac{1}{3}\Pi h^2(3r-h)]$, and can be found on *mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html*
2. The remaining volume  is $V_{slant}$. Realise the following: (a) $V_{slant}$ is not a wedge like the ones used for a door stopper, since it's "left" and "right" sides are part of spherical curvature; (b) $V_{slant}$ is not formed by a radius originating from $z_{cut}$ (I therefore did not use polar or spherical coordinates); (c) symmetry is not in our favour.

The last point (c) might not be true. However, up and till now, I could not see how to use symmetry. In fact, I attempted the construction of a symmetrical solution. Specifically, I completed the hemi-spherical drawing by extending the line into the RHS hemi-sphere. See the 2D sketch below (the $Y$-axis should actually be a $Z$-axis).

[image: 2D symmetry attempt]

From the sketch, one might get the impression that $V_1 = V_2 = V_{slant}$. If this is the case, then a solutioin based on symmetry might be constructed. But this *seems* to not be the case, since these two figures are not even congruent in 2D. *I use the word "seems", since congruent figures will have the same area and possibly volume, but figures with the same area or volume are not necessarily congruent*. By the cosine formula:
\begin{eqnarray}
r^2 = a^2 + z_{cut}^2 - 2az_{cut}\cos{(90^{\circ} + \theta)}\\
r^2 = b^2 + z_{cut}^2 - 2bz_{cut}\cos{(90^{\circ} - \theta)}
\end{eqnarray}

The above simplifies to:
\begin{equation}
b - a = 2z_{cut}sin{(\theta)} \neq 0
\end{equation}

This does not necessarily mean that $V_1 \neq V_2$, but it does causes disbelief.

To determine the volume ($V$) analytically I took the following approach: Determine $V_{slant}$ by constructing discs (with thickness $\Delta z$) parallel to the $XY$-plane and then sum these discs from $z_{cut}$ to $z_{upper}$ as $\Delta z \rightarrow 0$ ($z_{upper}$ is the $z$-coordinate where the plane cuts the hemi-sphere at $x = 0$).

Consider a horisontal disc (i.e. parallel to the $XY$-plane) at $z=k$. The integration boundaries to compute the area of this disc is given as:

\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
-\sqrt{r^2 - y^2 - k^2} \leq & x \leq \sqrt{r^2 - y^2 - k^2}\\
\sqrt{r^2 - k^2} \leq & y \leq \frac{k-z_{cut}}{grad}
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}

Hence,
\begin{equation}
A_k = \int_{-\sqrt{r^2 - k^2}}^{\frac{k-z_{cut}}{grad}}\int_{-\sqrt{r^2 - y^2 - k^2}}^{\sqrt{r^2 - y^2 - k^2}}dxdy
\end{equation}

Since z is a variable in the equation of the sphere, $A_k$ changes with different $z=k$, thus
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
A(z) &= \int_{-\sqrt{r^2 - z^2}}^{\frac{z-z_{cut}}{grad}}2\sqrt{r^2 - y^2-z^2}dy\\
&=  \bigg[y\sqrt{(r^2 - z^2) - y^2} + (r^2 - z^2)\arcsin{\Big(\frac{y}{\sqrt{r^2 - z^2}}\Big)}\bigg]_{-\sqrt{r^2 - z^2}}^{\frac{z-z_{cut}}{grad}}\\
&= \Big(\frac{z - z_{cut}}{grad}\Big)\sqrt{(r^2 - z^2) - \Big(\frac{z - z_{cut}}{grad}\Big)^2} + (r^2 - z^2)\arcsin{\Bigg(\frac{\frac{z - z_{cut}}{grad}}{\sqrt{r^2 - z^2}}\Bigg)} + \frac{\pi}{2}(r^2 - z^2)
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}

I tried to integrate the above equation with respect to $z$ in both MatLab and on the Wolfram Alpha website, but both programs gave complex answers. This might be a result of the domain constraint on arcsin between -1 and 1. Whatever the case might be, volume is physically still a real value in $[units]^3$.

Does any one know whether there is either:

1. An analytical solution to compute
   \begin{equation}
   V_{slant} = \int_{z_{cut}}^{z_{upper}}A(z)dz,
   \end{equation}
   or
2. A more elegant solution to the find the volume $V$?